# Gradle Import Sun Security Exception

Tags: eclipse, gradle, ssl-certificate, sslhandshakeexception, pkix

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Exception while Importing Gradle project in Eclipse Mars , It shown there are few certificates to be added in the Cacerts File of Java . 
I have added the certificates with the key tool. The certificates were added in the Cacerts file also. But again getting the Same SSL Error.tried Running Cmd prompt also. No use. one thing I am unable to try is Changing the Access permission of the Cacerts File.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems were

1. Proxy Firewall
2. The profile was customized for the Organization.

I was creating a project with the predefined profile format (like rest, angular).

Note : Before creating a project in grails 3.x make sure the profile you are using is Whether the customized one or Predefined in Grails.